# Flex: change item Style on certain Tree based ItemRenderers

Tags: apache-flex, tree, itemrenderer

I have a question concerning Tree items. I want to show where a drop action would be placed... The item will be placed in between two existing elements. So what I want to do is, to take the upper item and draw a line underneath it. But I struggling to address the itemRenderer...

I have the index for the itemrenderer, but I dont get a instance of that object.

Any help is appreciated!
Markus

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing drag & drop right, it should be showing a line where you are going to drop the dragItem. That is standard behavior. You shouldn't have to do that in the itemRenderer.

Comment: Thanks Robusto, but I didnt find any way to set the stile of only one line from the event:DragEvent variable. the only thing I can do is to take the event.currentTarget and change the border style of the whole Tree!... Markus